# When I'm testing create script in auth0 it use get user script. Why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, auth0

When I'm trying to use create script(button try in custom DB connection or try connection) Auth0 use get user script. Examples:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUIyj.png)

And then Auth0 use get user script. 
Here is my create script:

```
function create(user, callback) {

  var request = require('request');

  var API_ENDPOINT = configuration.ENDPOINT_LOCAL + "/api/create/account/";

  user.user_metadata = user.user_metadata || {};

  request.post({
    url: API_ENDPOINT,
    json: {
      email: user.email,
      password: user.password,
      nickname: user.user_metadata.nickname,
      employee_id: user.user_metadata.employee_id,
      company_code: user.user_metadata.company_code,
      email_verified: false
    }

  }, function (err, response, body) {
    if (err) {
      return callback(err);
    }
    if (response.statusCode != 200 && response.statusCode != 201) {
      return callback(new Error('Forbidden'));
    }
    callback(null);
  });
}
```

and Here is my get user script:

```
function getByEmail(email, callback) {

  var request = require('request');

  var IDP_ENDPOINT = configuration.ENDPOINT_LOCAL + "/api/account";

  request.get({
    url: IDP_ENDPOINT + '?email=' + email
  }, function (err, response, body) {

      if (err) {
        return callback(err);
      }
      if (response.statusCode != 200) {
        return callback(new Error('Forbidden'));
      }

      callback(null, JSON.parse(body));
  });
}
```

I really don't know why because two days before all were working.